# Bad performance Plotly Dash app deployed to Heroku

Tags: pandas, heroku, plotly-dash

I Would appreciate your help with an issue I'm having with a Dash app deployed to Heroku.
In my app, I have a graph component and Data.Tables that are refreshed every 5 minutes.
Additionally, I am using Callbacks to filter these graph and tables according to a select list.
To share the data between the callbacks and avoid multiple computations I am storing the data in the browser with a hidden Div.
The only thing the graph callback does is to get the jsonfied data and filter according to the select list and display the graph.

On my machine everything works well, but on Heroku the graph update time is long, something like 2-3 seconds. The tables however update quickly also on heroku.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How much data are you storing in the hidden div (just ballpark estimate, i.e. is it 1kB, 1MB or 100MB)?

Comment: @emher - Thanks for the reply. It's around 1MB, sometimes even less

Comment: do you think migrating it to AWS EBS improves the performance?